# SUM from Multiple tables?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum

I am writing a query for a colleague at work which will look at a series of products. 
See what products have been sold and how many they have sold to which customer.

I have done the following query:

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum] AS "Invoice Number"
     , T0.[CardName] AS "Customer Name"
     , T1.[ItemCode] AS "Item Code"
     , T1.[Quantity] AS "Quantity" 
FROM OINV T0
    INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
    INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode]
WHERE T2.[QryGroup7] = 'Y' AND (T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]')
ORDER BY T0.[CardName], T1.[ItemCode]
```

A few notes to add on this... WHERE DocDate [%0] is a parameter for SAP B1, and Invoice number in the SELECT can be removed... this has been added just as a reference point until i resolve this problem.

I have tried selecting Docnum/Cardname/ as MAX and Quantity as SUM, then adding these to the GROUP BY section.

If I am to run this query it would show the following...

```
Andy - Milk - 40
Andy - Milk - 40
Andy - Milk - 20
Bob - Carrots - 30
Bob -Carrots - 50
```

I want to treat "Cardname and Itemcode" as distinct, but sum "quantity"
To bring back a result of

```
"Andy - milk - 100"
"Bob - Carrots - 80"
```

I have had a good google around and can't seem to find anything what will work, and things I have tried I have just made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below with sum aggregation

```
SELECT T0.[CardName] AS "Customer Name"
, T1.[ItemCode] AS "Item Code"
, sum(T1.[Quantity]) AS "Quantity" 
FROM OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode]
WHERE T2.[QryGroup7] = 'Y' AND (T0.DocDate>='[%0]' and T0.DocDate<='[%1]')
group by T0.[CardName],T1.[ItemCode]
ORDER BY T0.[CardName], T1.[ItemCode]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works a charm... I'd been adding the SUM aggregate inside the Group by also which appears to have been the problem!
Thanks